# Script can't find library when run as cron job, works fine when run manually

Tags: shell, unix, cron, hp-ux

I am creating the script below in cronjob. It is manually getting generated. But, when in cron, it is failing to generate the files.

Below is my unix cron script.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash
var=`perl -w -e '$d=1*86400;@t=localtime (time -$d); printf "%.2d%.2d%.2d", $t[5]+1900,$t[4]+1,$t[3];'`

var="`echo $var |cut -c3-8`"

i=1;

while [ $i -le 8 ]
do

    cd /home/svfe/bin
    ./bills_unloader -d $var -f $i
    i=`expr $i + 1`
done

echo "Done !
```

---

When I try to debug the script, I am finding below error.

> /usr/lib/hpux64/dld.so: Unable to find library 'libclntsh.so.11.1'.
>   /home/swa/swa2/autoload/bills_unloader.sh: line 19:  7078 Killed
>   ./bills_unloader -d 170606 -f $i

Why is the command failing in cron, but working fine when executed manually?

Comment: Did you see the excellent debugging advice in the [crontab tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cron/info)?

Comment: @BenjaminW. It seems this debugging advice is, how to say that, a little bit recursive at the very moment.

Comment: @ArturR.Czechowski That is a shame. The crontab tag wiki was an excellent debugging guide, but it's synonymized to "cron" now. Has been since January 16, apparently, which is strange – I'm sure I've seen the debugging guide more recently than that.

Comment: Here is the [archived tag wiki](https://web.archive.org/web/20160804040638/http://stackoverflow.com/tags/crontab/info).

Comment: @BenjaminW. I\ve just asked on meta if it's possible to restore lost wiki: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350576/it-is-possible-to-restore-wiki-of-tag-aliased-to-another-tag

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you have `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable set in your CLI environment, but it is not available when script is run under cron. Add a line:

```
declare -x > /tmp/variables.log.$(date +%s).$$
```

at the beginning of the script, the compare the logs from manual run and cron run. If necessary, set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` properly in your script.

As it is a hpux system, it could be also `SHLIB_PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

You might be using command with another user and crontab with another.
Suppose your command is working fine with user "xyz" try below command in your crontab entry -
su - xyz -c sh